# How to pass entire json string to a field of nested struct while unmarshaling?

Tags: go, struct, tags

I need to unmarshal flat json string

```
data := `{"login":"Nickname","password":"some_pass","newPassword":"new_pass"}`
```

into the `UpdatePasswordRequest` nested structure:

```
type SignInRequest struct {
    Login    string `json:"login"`
    Password string `json:"password"`
}

type UpdatePasswordRequest struct {
    NewPassword string        `json:"newPassword"`
    SignInData  SignInRequest `<tag>`
}
```

Unmarshaling `data` to the `result` with all possible `<tag>` values

```
var result UpdatePasswordRequest
json.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &result)
```

gives empty `Login` and `Password`:

```
result.SignInData.Login = ""
result.SignInData.Password = ""
```

How should I define the `<tag>` to get correct values for `Login` and `Password` fields?

Comment: You can use embedding and no tag. I.e. from `UpdatePasswordRequest` remove `SignInData` and `<tag>`; and keep only `SignInRequest`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to use a name for the `<tag>`, your json should be nested, not flat, like this:

```
data := `{"newPassword":"new_pass", "myTag":{"password":"some_pass", "login":"Nickname"}}`
```

If you can't change your json, should compose the structs ( aka. struct embedding ) like this:

```
type SignInRequest struct {
    Login    string `json:"login"`
    Password string `json:"password"`
}

type UpdatePasswordRequest struct {
    NewPassword string        `json:"newPassword"`
    SignInRequest
}
```